# How to search through String in Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm new to swift. Looking to solve this puzzle... can anybody enlighten me how i can use the old-style indexOf parameter of one string to pass into another?

[image: Can anybody solve this?]

Comment: "in the question itself" means as *text* so it can be indexed and and searched for, not *as a picture*.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check the string's characters. Like this:

```
str.characters.indexOf("a")
```

And this will return the index of the character "a" in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1:

The `hash` function:

```
func hash(s: String) -> Int {
  let letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw"
  return (s.characters.startIndex..<s.characters.endIndex).reduce(7) { (h, currentIndex) -> Int in
    let codeUnit = s.characters[currentIndex]
    let startIndex = letters.characters.startIndex
    let endIndex = letters.characters.indexOf(codeUnit)!
    let index = startIndex.distanceTo(endIndex)
    return h * 37 + index
  }
}

let sevenLetter = hash("leepadg")
print(sevenLetter) // prints 680131659347
```

Part 2:

```
// based on https://blog.hjm.im/hashing-puzzle/
func reverseHash(hash: Int, allowedCharacters: [Character]) -> String {
  var hash = hash
  var indices = [Int: Int]()
  var i = 0
  while hash > 37 {
    indices[i] = hash % 37
    hash = hash / 37
    i += 1
  }
  return (indices.count - 1).stride(through: 0, by: -1).reduce("") {
    $0 + String(allowedCharacters[indices[$1]!])
  }
}

let chars: [Character] = ["a", "c", "d", "e", "g", "i", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "t", "u", "w"]
print(reverseHash(680131659347, allowedCharacters: chars)) // prints "leepadg"
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to replace the hash with the right one :)